# Can't add Printer by IP Mac OS x Lion

Tags: osx-lion, ip, network-printer, macbook-air

I can't even see an option for printer type, where usually Fax, Windows, IP buttons are (toolbar on the top). See picture.

[image]

How is that possible and how can I add printer manually by IP?

Comment: How did you access this menu?

Comment: Preferences -> Print & Scan -> +

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this is not really an answer to the questions why you can't do it. But this should allow you to install a printer:

open safari and go to

`http://localhost:631`

that is the CUPS web interface for your local printing system. you should be able to do things like adding a removing printers in there. if it tells you that the web interface is disabled open a terminal and type:

`sudo cupsctl WebInterface=yes`